# Attaching multiple web pages to one WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, webview, android-webview

I have developed an application in which **webView** is used to explain different posts,I have implemented the webView on an floating button but the problem is that when I click the floating button only **1 webpage shows on all** posts. I want to attach **different web pages** to **different posts** using only **one webView**, I am using **firebase** and through Firebase database I can add different webpages but they are not accessible. I have searched many questions and did not find anything useful, please help.

> I am using Android Studio

**webView class file:**

```
public class webViewNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webviewthis;
    private DatabaseReference mdataRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("weber");
        webviewthis = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mdataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                post2web webView = dataSnapshot.getValue(post2web.class);
                webviewthis.loadUrl(webView.getWebViewPost());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Webview xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView_news"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So your problem is you click on a button and that should open a new webpage?

Comment: @Steven yes, new webpage on new post, not like i click on button and same webpage opens on all posts.

Comment: @rRohitB I don't understand what you want. How do you want to navigate to an other webpage?

Comment: @Steven i want that the button i click take me to a web page in a webView but it should be connected with the post of recyclerView . for eg if there is a post which shows item 1 and i click the webView button the item 1st web Page opens and if there is a second post which shows item 2 the 2nd web page opens in same webView with same button clicked. I hope you got it, if not ask me again.

Comment: @rRohitB are you able to open one page?

Comment: @Steven yes i am able to open one page.

Comment: @rRohitB But not able to open a second page when you click on the webview button? The webview button is that a button in your html?

Comment: @Steven its not in html its in my android application and yes i am unable to open second webpage, i guess there is something with fragments

Comment: @rRohitB I think you will need the function `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to load the other webpage instead of that one

Comment: @Steven but how i will attach the same webView to all posts in recyclerView

Comment: @rRohitB sorry for my late answer. I don't see anything on your code with recyclerView? So I don't know what your are planning to do with it